# Adding a vertical scrollbar to a checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, vertical-scrolling, checkedlistbox

My CheckedListBox is containing some elements that has a higher width that the CheckedListBox it self. I would have expected that vertical scrollbars where displayed automaticly just like they appear when the list grows higher than the CheckedListBox. But this is not the case.

Is there some setting i need to set to get the CheckedListBox to show vertical scrollbars?

Comment: sounds like your design is wrong. if your item is that wide, it is probably better to have additional expanded view. So, when you move your mouse over the item, the view will show more information.

Comment: Since you are not telling which technology (Web, WinForms, WPF, W8) you are targeting, just a vague suggestion: Put your control in a scrollable container that gets scrollbars when the content exceeds the size.

Comment: Sorry about that ! Im using Winforms..

Comment: I think you need to re-word your question. You say your elements have a higher *width* but you're expecting vertical scrollbars? Either you meant height, or horizontal scrollbars.

For me, vertical bars appear automatically. Horizontal bars only appear if you set HorizontalScrollbar to true.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can set property in your code

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    // Enable HorizontalScrollbar 
    this.CheckedListBox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Scrollbars property to Both.

Comment: There is no prooperty on my CheckedListBox named Scrollbars